# Translating the Phrase from 20th to the 18th century

Tags: phrases, dictionaries

Needing to write a novel that is set in the 1800's finding the correct phrases and words used back then is challenging. I just want to know where I can find the correct phrases and words for the novel. Is there a website that can help or a 1800 dictionary.

Comment: Resource requests should be over on meta.

Comment: You find them in books and newspapers and letters written then.

Comment: I believe this question would be much better served over on https://writing.stackexchange.com/ - You will find people there who are also writing the same kind of novel.  Meanwhile check out modern copies of *Sheridan's Pronouncing the Spelling Dictionary*, written in 1800, which can be bought online in a 2010 reprint.

Comment: A word of advice from those of us who are technically minded. Be very careful to avoid anachronisms, especially in the field of inventions and historical events. Timelines are extremely useful, e.g.  https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Timeline_of_historic_inventions#1800s

Comment: 'The 1800s' is actually the 19th century, and was a period of many changes which would affect the language spoken.

Answer (score 1):

Various dictionaries from 1800 or thereabout are available online. For British English, H.J. Todd's four-volume revision of Samuel Johnson's *A Dictionary of the English Language* (with full citations) from 1818 is probably the most detailed:

[Volume 1 (A–C)](https://books.google.com/books?id=jR_Qs0gH6TYC&pg=PT222&dq=%22weed+that+grows+in+furrowed+land%22&hl=en&sa=X&ved=0ahUKEwi8_YnEvvTaAhUJCXwKHTlRDIE4ChDoAQhGMAU#v=onepage&q=%22weed%20that%20grows%20in%20furrowed%20land%22&f=false)

[Volume 2 (D–H)](https://books.google.com/books?id=8cE_AQAAMAAJ&pg=PT8&dq=%22Dictionary+of+the+English+Language%22+1818&hl=en&sa=X&ved=0ahUKEwjE4oDttbbTAhVIwGMKHSSoBeMQ6AEINTAD#v=onepage&q=%22Dictionary%20of%20the%20English%20Language%22%201818&f=false)

[Volume 3 (I–Q)](https://books.google.com/books?id=YHyTyj139-UC&pg=PT8&dq=%22grammar+by+the+rev.+H.+J.+Todd%22&hl=en&sa=X&ved=0ahUKEwjzvI7ts7bTAhVJ4GMKHWy5AKQQ6AEIJTAA#v=onepage&q=%22grammar%20by%20the%20rev.%20H.%20J.%20Todd%22&f=false)

[Volume 4 (R–Z)](https://books.google.com/books?id=zsI_AQAAMAAJ&pg=PP17&dq=%22dr+johnson+barely+notices+the+Fr+word%22&hl=en&newbks=1&newbks_redir=0&sa=X&ved=2ahUKEwjPvsqKoortAhXlLX0KHUjRA0oQ6AEwAHoECAEQAg#v=onepage&q=%22dr%20johnson%20barely%20notices%20the%20Fr%20word%22&f=false)

A two-volume English dictionary from the same general period is Thomas Sheridan, *A Complete Dictionary of the English Language*, revised edition (1797):

[Volume 1 (A–H)](https://books.google.com/books?id=pUkG2VwfxhoC&printsec=frontcover&dq=%22A+Complete+Dictionary%22+%22Thomas+Sheridan%22&hl=en&newbks=1&newbks_redir=0&sa=X&ved=2ahUKEwj7-aTupIrtAhVVtZ4KHcRqBBkQ6AEwA3oECAUQAg#v=onepage&q=%22A%20Complete%20Dictionary%22%20%22Thomas%20Sheridan%22&f=false)

[Volume 2 (I–Z)](https://books.google.com/books?id=z-YIAAAAQAAJ&printsec=frontcover&dq=%22A+Complete+Dictionary%22+%22Thomas+Sheridan%22&hl=en&newbks=1&newbks_redir=0&sa=X&ved=2ahUKEwj7-aTupIrtAhVVtZ4KHcRqBBkQ6AEwAHoECAMQAg#v=onepage&q=%22A%20Complete%20Dictionary%22%20%22Thomas%20Sheridan%22&f=false)

A single-volume option is Stephen Jones, [*Sheridan Improved: A General Pronouncing a Explanatory Dictionary of the English Language*](https://books.google.com/books?id=sDVAAAAAYAAJ&pg=PT606&dq=%22a+preservative+that+which+prevents%22&hl=en&sa=X&ved=0CFAQ6AEwCWoVChMI2626k9rYxgIVAlGICh1gBAsz#v=onepage&q=%22a%20preservative%20that%20which%20prevents%22&f=false), third edition (1798).

For U.S. English (largely cribbed from Johnson and other British English sources), the first large-scale source is Noah Webster, *An American Dictionary of the English Language* (1828), available through Google Books in a two-volume set:

[Volume 1 (A–I)](https://books.google.com/books?id=699BAQAAMAAJ&dq=%22each+other%22+%22one+another%22&q=%22each+other%22+%22one+another%22#v=snippet&q=%22each%20other%22%20%22one%20another%22&f=false)

[Volume 2 (J–Z)](https://books.google.com/books?id=7aJHAQAAMAAJ&pg=PP527&dq=%22the+wax+set+to+an+instrument%22&hl=en&newbks=1&newbks_redir=0&sa=X&ved=2ahUKEwjT6ZiuqortAhW1GDQIHbe3DDoQ6AEwAHoECAIQAg#v=onepage&q=%22the%20wax%20set%20to%20an%20instrument%22&f=false)